# Fundamental volume of quotient group

Tags: group-theory, integer-lattices

I came across this rule in my old notes, but I need an explanation to how it could possibly originate:

The theorem says that for any lattice $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the order of the quotient group, $\lvert L/aL\rvert$, where $a$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^n$, is given by $\text{vol}(aL)/\text{vol}(L)=|a|^n$

Any explanation for this rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try considering the case of $L = \mathbb{Z}^n$ and see if it doesn't clear something up:

If $L = \mathbb{Z}^n$, then $a L$ consists of the points of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ where every coordinate is divisible by $a$, so the quotient $L / a L$ has a total of $a^n$ representatives, namely

$$(0, \ldots, 0), (0, \ldots, 1), \ldots, (a-1, \ldots, a-1)$$

In general, when you multiply $L$ by $a$, you're "thinning out the lattice" by a factor of $a$ in $n$ different dimensions, so $a L$ will be $1/a^n$ the size of $L$, and consequently $|L / a L| = a^n$.

UPDATE:  As HSN points out in the comments, apparently the source of confusion is that you have $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ rather than $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ in the notes.  I'm not an expert and I won't swear to it, but surely that's just a mistake -- see my comment below.

Comment: Don't you need $a$ to be an integer? This is what I'd expect as well, but I can't make sense of the remark "where $a$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^n$ yet. How is $aL$ even defined? Or how can one form the quotient?

Comment: Ah, yes, I was working under the assumption that $a$ was an integer, but I see now he's written $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  That can't possibly be right, though -- consider $n = 1$ and $L = \mathbb{Z}$.  Then the only sublattices of $L$ are $a L$ for $a$ an integer, so there's no sensible way to make sense of $a L$ for arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{R}$.  I guess his notes just have a mistake.

Comment: Fair enough. I think we agree then.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this surely helps. And regarding HSN's comment, I also believe it must be a mistake in my notes!